# Roll out a beta version in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I want to roll out my app to the testers by using the Google Play Store and publishing it as a beta version.
I've completed all the steps listed by google (including uploading the apk, updating all the store entries, setting images and so on)- furthermore I've created a beta entry for the app.

My issue now is, that there is no opt-in url for the testers to download the app, although the status sais that the app has been rolled out, as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

What should I change in order to get the app to the stage where the testers can download it from the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After waiting a couple of minutes (and drinking a cup of coffee) the opt-in link suddenly appeared after waiting for one and a half hour. Patience was the key!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

see you can get beta testers

1. either set the list of testers email id in your developer console by
   grouping them together in a field.
2. And then out out for beta testing
3. select max number of tester
4. those who are tester send them the url for the application you want
   to test
   5)They are going to test it and send you the feedback

Comment: Hi! My question was why I didn't get the OPT-IN url for the testers, but I've got it now. Patience was the key. Thanks though!

Comment: ya it might take some time to get the url